# Programmatic Access to Visual Basic Project is not trusted from IIS

Tags: vba, asp.net-web-api, ms-word, iis-7

I'm using an executable which tries to access the VBA object model programmatically by importing and running VBA macros in Word07.
If I call that executable from command line everything works fine (macro settings are accordingly set in MS Word) but if I try to start that executable from within a Web API service that is hosted in IIS 7, I get the error message "Programmatic Access to Visual Basic Project is not trusted".
I already changed the identity of the IIS application pool to the windows user and to LocalSystem but nothing works.
Any ideas?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This setting is not in the system, but in the Word application.

- Run Word as the same user as is set in DCOM configuration
- Click office-logo-button and click Word options (it is not exact, because I haven't English Word, so I'm only guessing translation)
- in security setting click button of Security center setting (again, lost in translation...)
- in Macro setting, check "Trust object model access of VBA projects"

Note that in DCOM setting must be set named user for launching and *Load User Profile* must be *true*, but this you have probably done.

One useful link: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/257757/en-us

Comment: You made my day ;) The macro security settings were already set correctly but the user in the DCOM configuration of Word was not set.

Comment: I also had this issue and resolved it by doing the following, based on suggestions in this answer:

Open DCOM Config, Find the entry named "Microsoft Word 97 - 2003 Document",
Right click and open properties,
Navigate to identity tab,
Check radio button "This user" and specify the user your executable is running as.